# How do I figure out if a record is a page or a post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am in search.php and I get, for a certain query, a set of results (pages and posts). Now, within the loop I am using to display such results, I need to figure out if the current item is actually a post or a page.

How do I do that? Is there a conditional tag to do it? I couldn't find it :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is_page( $post->ID )` for pages and `is_single( $post->ID )` for posts.

Comment: And it works inside the loop and applies to the current item being looped over?

Comment: Yes - use this inside the loop and it will tell you if the current entry is a page or post.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve and check the post type of a post with [`get_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type).

```
echo 'The post type is: ' . get_post_type( get_the_ID() );
```

Answer (score -1):

The right answer is the following (sorry guys):

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   <?php if ($post->post_type === "post"): ?>
      it's a post!
   <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```